# Is there a tool to visualize RNA secondary structure?

Tags: visualization, rna

I want to manually fold and pair two sequences (U4 and U6). And I want to make niceish figures.

I haven't found a single program that does that.

thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi @user3392394 and welcome. The question is difficult to understand. Are you trying to perform two individual RNA structures, or is this two sequences to make a single structure? There are lots of programs for RNA structure, what I suspect is you have a specific project in mind, which is not being clearly communicated. Alternatively are you just looking for a RNA 2D structure viewer?

Answer (score 1):

The RNA viewer that is particularly good is [VA RNA](http://varna.lri.fr). This stands for "Visualisation Applet for RNA". Its a java app and run it via,

```
java -jar /Route2Progam/vaRNA/VARNAv3-93-API.jar
```

Where `Route2Progam` is the path to where the jar files is stored, all other info in the run code is literal.

Very nice pictures, point and clicky, drag structures into different shapes and easy to colour ... so for a GUI its great.

They recommend [PsuedoViewer](http://wilab.inha.ac.kr/pseudoviewer/) for psuedoknots, but if that doesn't mean much ... it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

You could try mxfold2.
https://github.com/mxfold/mxfold2

```
% mxfold2 predict test.fa
>DS4440
GGAUGGAUGUCUGAGCGGUUGAAAGAGUCGGUCUUGAAAACCGAAGUAUUGAUAGGAAUACCGGGGGUUCGAAUCCCUCUCCAUCCG
(((((((........(((((..((((.....))))...)))))...................(((((.......)))))))))))). (24.8)
```